# How do I score rounds 2 and 3 when I am the only player with a kind of building?

Tags: alhambra

Last night at the end of round 2, I was the only player with any Pavilion tiles in my Alhambra. First place gets 8 points, second place gets 1 point. How do I score this? Do I get all 9 points? Or just the 8 points for first place? It's only 1 point, but I could see a situation with higher-value kind of buildings where this division would matter.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You only get the points for first place. There simply is no second place person to receive those points. If a game wanted to let you get the second place points also in that case, it would need to be spelled out as a special rule.

Answer (score 3):

Quoting from the rules on second round scoring :-

"points are awarded to the players with the highest number and second highest number of building tiles of each type."

Later it says "You must have at least 1 building tile of a particular type to be awarded points for that category".

So lets say you have 2 pavilions and the 2 other players have 0.  You have have come first and get 8 points.  the other players score nothing.  You have not come 1st, 2nd and 3rd in this category to entitle you to all the points.